# Правильно ли стоят запятые? [1]

Tags: пунктуация

> Отправляю через почту, так что не знаю как скоро она придёт.

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Корректно: *Отправляю через почту, так что не знаю, как скоро она придет*.

Запятая перед *как* нужна, потому что начинается новое предложение с грамматической основой *она придет*.

Возможно, лучше написать: *отправляю **по** почте*.